# How to remove the identical elements between 2 lists?

Tags: tcl

I have 2 lists with some identical elements, and I want to remove these elements between these 2 lists; Example would be like this:

```
set list_1 [list a b c d]
set list_2 [list e f b a]
puts $list_1_remove_identical ; #Output that I want
c d
puts $list_2_remove_identical ; 
e f
```

Comment: Are the starting lists full of unique elements or are there repetitions in the inputs? (Yes, some are in both lists or you wouldn't be asking the question, but are there any *other* dupes?) Does the order of elements matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a dict](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) to store the elements of one list for fast lookup to see if they're present in the other list, and only keep the ones that aren't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc list_difference {a b} {
    set in_b [dict create]
    foreach elem $b {
        dict set in_b $elem 1
    }
    lmap elem $a { if {[dict exists $in_b $elem]} { continue } else { set elem } }
}

set list_1 [list a b c d]
set list_2 [list e f b a]
puts [list_difference $list_1 $list_2] ;# c d
puts [list_difference $list_2 $list_1] ;# e f
```

Answer (score 0):

As Donal points out correctly, it depends on the nature of the two lists to be compared. For example, if you are looking at sets (no duplicates, ordering not relevant), then you might use tcllib's [`struct::set`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_set.md#6):

```
% package req struct
2.1
% set list_1 [list a b c d]
a b c d
% set list_2 [list e f b a]
e f b a
% struct::set difference $list_1 $list_2
d c
% struct::set difference $list_2 $list_1
e f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to check for each element if it exists in the other list:

```
puts [lmap n $list_1 {if {$n in $list_2} continue;set n}]
puts [lmap n $list_2 {if {$n in $list_1} continue;set n}]
```